# The product of logarithms

Tags: optimization, logarithms

I was studying logarithms and got stuck with this problem. Is there anyone who can solve this?
Thank you in advance. The question - Given that $p$ and $q$ are positive and that $\ 4(\log_{10} 
p)^2+2(\log_{10} q)^2=9$ , find the greatest possible value of p such that the equality holds.

Edit

As per asker's note, the answer is:$10\sqrt 10$

Comment: For the greatest $p$, $4(\log p)^2$ _(you might want to fix that typo)_ would also be the greatest. In order for that, we need to minimize the value of $2(\log q)^2$. Do you see something? 

Comment: The answer is $\ 10\sqrt10$ but I do not know how to solve that.

Comment: Have you tried what I said in my comment?

Comment: Not yet. How can I minimize the value of $\ 2(log_{10} q)^2$.

Comment: Well, the minimum value of $\log q$ is $0$ when $q=1$, so you can make it $4(\log p)^2=9\implies(\log p)^2=\frac94$ and $\log p=\frac32\implies p=10^\frac32=10\sqrt{10}$ (By the way, $\log p$ is the same as $\log_{10} p$). Haidara's method also works 

Comment: Thank you for your time

Comment: No problem! Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is really simple. First you have the equality $4(\log_{10}p)^2+2(\log_{10}q)^2=9$
Then, $9-4(\log_{10}p)^2=2(\log_{10}q)^2$
Now we factor the left hand side, $(3-2(\log_{10}p))(3+2(\log_{10}p))=2(\log_{10}q)^2$. Because the right hand side should always be positive, we deduce that the greatest value of $p$ is when:
$2(\log_{10}p)=3$

This is because if $2(\log_{10}p)>3$, then the left hand side is negative. Therefore, $2(\log_{10}p)\leq3$ so 3 is the greatest value that the expression can take:

$\log_{10}p=\frac{1}{2}$

$p=10^{1.5}$

Comment: @Kyo had this answered your question?

Comment: Thank you. That answered my question but I do not quite understand how you did that.

Comment: Notice that the right handside should always be positive because its a square of some number so by studying the sign of the left handside you can deduce that $2(log_{10}p)<=3$.@Kyo

Comment: Hmm... the right hand side can be zero, right?

Comment: True@TheMather-orratherAMather

Comment: Also, you're looking for the greatest $p$ so that $(3-2\log p)(3+2\log p)\geq0$, right? You might want to make that bit clearer 

Comment: @TheMather-orratherAMather true. Sorry about that I am writing from mobike can you edit it for me?

Comment: @Haidara haha, I'm also a mobile user! Maybe you can just add some explanation.

Comment: @TheMather-orratherAMather done :)

Comment: Alright, nice! 

Comment: @TheMather-orratherAMather can you help me?https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4707412/1185351

Comment: Thank you so much guys

Comment: @Haidara I guess you already got an answer, and I'm not the best at complex numbers anyway 

Comment: @TheMather-orratherAMather nice to meet you bro.

Comment: @Haidara nice to meet you, too!