# On the coefficients of two equal power series

Tags: functions, complex-numbers, power-series

I have two functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ that are defined as power series such that the coefficients are complex numbers and $x$ is a real number.
If I know that $f(x)=g(x)$ in their whole radius of convergence, does that mean the coefficients of both power series are equal? If so, how can we prove?
please help.

Comment: May you provide what you have tried to see if what you're asking is true or not? Also, I removed the abstract algebra tag because it is not relevant to the question.

Comment: Thanks @Accelerator .It's just a normal question i am asking about a general result not specifying any thing rather than the question context.

Comment: Compare the values of the derivatives of your functions at the center of the circle of convergence

Comment: Is this proof sufficient?@MarianoSuárez-Álvarez

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez notice that i said that the coefficients are complex numbers but x is always real so does the same rules apply?

Comment: If the series has a positive radius of convergence in the real numbers then it also has a positive radius of convergence in the complex numbers (the same, in fact) so that does not change anything — but if you prefer, compute real derivatives.

Comment: (you should probably consult a textbook treatment on power series!)

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez can you provide me one?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez i think i understood your argument thanks.